# Is there a function for extraction not a principal root?

Tags: python

There is a function from `math` module, named `sqrt`, which returns a principal square root of a number. For example, `math.sqrt(4)` yields `2` as an answer.

My question is, is there a function, which can return not only one root, but also the second one. Consider the following code `func(4)` yields `(2, -2)`, since `-2**2 == 2**2 == 4`.

Comment: No, not in the `math` module at least. Why don't you just write your own?

Comment: r3mainer, because I want core python developers to implement it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there isn't any. But it should not be a problem tho, since you just need the negative of a value. You need to write your own method which also returns the negative of `math.sqrt()`.